# Check existence in SELECT query

Tags: sql, postgresql

What I get from function getPattern(integer) is:

[image]

Where '....3...' is a pattern( like comp3333 is matched).

I want to print out all patterns which doesn't include '.'

So I do:

```
 SELECT pattern as pn 
 FROM getPattern($1)
 WHERE EXISTS (SELECT pattern as pr  
               FROM getPattern($1) 
               WHERE pr ~* '^[A-Z]{4}[0-9]{4}$')
   AND pn ~* '^[A-Z]{4}[0-9]{4}$'
```

Sometimes when we use the function getPattern(int), the result may not include any pattern without '.', and this is what error shows:

[image]

What should I do in a neat way?

Comment: It seems like the error message does not match with your description. Could  you please give again your idea?

Comment: There is a table containing all the subject codes( e.g comp3333), I have to find all the subject codes which match one of patterns from the table I get from getPattern(). If I directly check each code, it will take a long time, so I want to extract all complete patterns from getPattern() (like EDSR4172 rather than ....3...) so that I don't have to check these codes again from subject table.

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use an alias in a WHERE clause. In this subquery there is no need for one anyway:

```
(SELECT pattern as pr FROM getPattern($1) WHERE pr ~* '^[A-Z]{4}[0-9]{4}$')
```

so just change it to:

```
(SELECT pattern FROM getPattern($1) WHERE pattern ~* '^[A-Z]{4}[0-9]{4}$')
```